# What is the {# .. #} comment syntax from?

Tags: html, syntax, comments

I saw `{# ... #}` syntax used to comment out things in an HTML template. This is, as far as I know, not a part of "vanilla" HTML. What is this syntax from and in what contexts is it valid?

[Edit] Follow-up question. How would I google for the answer to this? I tried putting the syntax in quotes but that did not work.

Comment: Google probably won't be useful here. Doing a [structural search](https://docs.sourcegraph.com/code_search/reference/structural) on [sourcegraph.com](https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=context:global+%7B%23...%23%7D+count:100&patternType=structural) shows that this is used at least by  [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/) and [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/) (judging from the file paths)

Comment: I think I searched for `comments {#`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a comment in Jinja templating engine https://jinja.palletsprojects.com

As seen here:
https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#comments

Comment: Thanks. Twig was also mentioned, and I found out Twig syntax is partly based on Jinja.

Comment: The Python Django Framework (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/templates/) also uses this comment-syntax.